# Java - how to encode URL path for non Latin characters

Tags: java, android, url, unicode

Currently there is `final URL url = new URL(urlString);` but I run into server not supporting non-ASCII in path.

Using Java (Android) I need to encode URL from

```
http://acmeserver.com/download/agc/fcms/儿子去哪儿/儿子去哪儿.png
```

to

```
http://acmeserver.com/download/agc/fcms/%E5%84%BF%E5%AD%90%E5%8E%BB%E5%93%AA%E5%84%BF/%E5%84%BF%E5%AD%90%E5%8E%BB%E5%93%AA%E5%84%BF.png
```

just like browsers do.

I checked `URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");` but it also encodes `/` slashes

```
http%3A%2F%2acmeserver.com%2Fdownload%2Fagc%2Ffcms%2F%E5%84%BF%E5%AD%90%E5%8E%BB%E5%93%AA%E5%84%BF%2F%E5%84%BF%E5%AD%90%E5%8E%BB%E5%93%AA%E5%84%BF.png
```

**Is there way to do it simply without parsing string that the method gets?**

from http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars

> B.2.1 Non-ASCII characters in URI attribute values Although URIs do
>   not contain non-ASCII values (see [URI], section 2.1) authors
>   sometimes specify them in attribute values expecting URIs (i.e.,
>   defined with %URI; in the DTD). For instance, the following href value
>   is illegal:
>
> `<A href="http://foo.org/Håkon">...</A>`
>
> We recommend that user agents adopt the following convention for
>   handling non-ASCII characters in such cases:
>
> 1. Represent each character in UTF-8 (see [RFC2279]) as one or more
>      bytes.
> 2. Escape these bytes with the URI escaping mechanism (i.e., by
>      converting each byte to %HH, where HH is the hexadecimal notation of
>      the byte value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final URL url = new URL( new URI(urlString).toASCIIString() );
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

You should just encode the special characters and the parse them together. If you tried to encode the entire URI then you'd run into problems.

Stick with:

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("apples oranges", "utf-8");
String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" + query;
```

Check out this [great guide](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) on URL encoding.

That being said, a little bit of searching suggests that there may be other ways to do what you want:

Give this a try:

```
String urlStr = "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
url = uri.toURL();
```

(You will need to have those spaces encoded so you can use it for a request.)

> This takes advantage of a couple features available to you in Android
>   classes.  First, the URL class can break a url into its proper
>   components so there is no need for you to do any string search/replace
>   work.  Secondly, this approach takes advantage of the URI class
>   feature of properly escaping components when you construct a URI via
>   components rather than from a single string.
>
> The beauty of this approach is that you can take any valid url string
>   and have it work without needing any special knowledge of it yourself.

Comment: OK, so anyway an URI object is to be created.

Comment: Yes. The URI is the location address. If you never had a URI, then your app would never know where to send/receive the request.

Comment: I tried as one liner `final URL url = new URI(urlString).toURL();` but it did not encode path.

Comment: @PaulVerest Well yes that's because you didn't encode the urlString - it's just a String. You never used any encoding. Additionally, why can't you encode just the variable text? (like the query) That should be a guaranteed way to work.

Answer (score 2):

I did it as below, which is cumbersome

```
        //was: final URL url = new URL(urlString);
        String asciiString;
        try {
            asciiString = new URL(urlString).toURI().toASCIIString();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error new URL(urlString).toURI().toASCIIString() " + urlString + " : " + e1);
            return null;
        }
        Log.v(TAG, urlString+" -> "+ asciiString );
        final URL url = new URL(asciiString);
```

`url` is later used in

```
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Comment: Just curious, but isn't that a little redundant? You're taking a string, converting it to a URL, converting it back to a string - via toURI(), and then encoding it with toASCIIString(). (So essentially you are encoding it, just all in one line.) `public String toASCIIString()
Returns the content of this URI as a US-ASCII string.
If this URI does not contain any characters in the other category then an invocation of this method will return the same value as an invocation of the toString method. Otherwise this method works as if by invoking that method and then encoding the result.`

Comment: Yes, this is redundant.