# Unable to concatenate String in url where String contains unicodes and get from EditText?

Tags: android, url, unicode, android-volley, unicode-string

I am using volley library for json i have done

```
           String   header=sirsak.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
            Log.d("header::",header); //here sirsak is edit text***strong text***
```

to take String from edit text..

and tried to concatenate  with url

```
      String posturl="http://54.193.70.29:8080/ghosanapatra/message/addMessageA?message=message&cId=1&heading="+header+"&eId=1&pId=268&wId=1&name=name&memberFbId=123&phone=9860327645";

     StringRequest postrequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,posturl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                   pd=new ProgressDialog(GiveSujab.this);
                    pd.setMessage("loading.");
                    pd.setCancelable(false);
                    pd.show();
                    try {
                        JSONObject saveobj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String savestatus = saveobj.getString("save");
                        if (savestatus.equals("sucess")) {
                            Toast.makeText(GiveSujab.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(GiveSujab.this,MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(GiveSujab.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    pd.dismiss();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
     });

            requestqueue.add(postrequest);
```

It works when i type English text in EditText but not working when i type in Nepali language like"नेपाली"
It shows like 
 [http://54.193.70.29:8080/ghosanapatra/message/addMessageA?message=message&cId=1&heading=नेप](http://54.193.70.29:8080/ghosanapatra/message/addMessageA?message=message&cId=1&heading=%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%AA)ालीको&eId=1&pId=268&wId=1&name=name&memberFbId=123&phone=9860327645

How can i solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254051/java-how-to-encode-url-path-for-non-latin-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the code

```
             String header = sirsak.getText().toString();
                String encode = URLEncoder.encode(header,"UTF-8");
```

its very simple

Answer (score 0):

this is an encoding issue, try this to get past this error
before doing this line

```
String   header=sirsak.getText().toString().replace(" ","");
```

Do this

```
System.out.println(sirsak); //watch what it outputs here
```

Then

```
System.out.println(new String(sirsak.getBytes("UTF-8"))); //watch what it outputs
```

Or do this

```
System.out.println(new String(sirsak.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```

One of them should give you the correct format. Suppose

```
sirsak.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

gives you the correct format, just reassign it to a new string as follows

```
String newSirsak = sirsak.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

and use this in your code. Hope you find this useful.

Thanks

Comment: getByte is not supporting

Comment: sirsak is a String I assume, hence it should work If it is not, then instead of sirsak do the same thing with sirsak.getText().toString().getBytes(). Then it should work.

Documentation of getBytes() -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()

Comment: sirsak=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.header);and    String  header=sirsak.getText().toString().getBytes(); is also not working

Answer (score 0):

```
String uri = Uri.parse(""http://54.193.70.29:8080/ghosanapatra/message/addMessageA")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
 .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
 .appendQueryParameter("key", "val")
                .build().toString();
```

Comment: can you explain ?

Comment: its simple just pass this  String uri in volley  method. appendQueryParameter("key", "val") is adds key value as query string. For example if write 

String uri = Uri.parse("htttp:/www.google.com")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("name", "rajesh")
 .appendQueryParameter("id", "55")

                .build().toString(); then your url would become "http://www.google.com/name=rajesh&id=55"

Comment: when i use direct value in url then its workhttp://54.193.70.29:8080/ghosanapatra/message/addMessageA?message=message&cId=1&heading=नगरपालिका&eId=1&pId=268&wId=1&name=name&memberFbId=123&phone=9860327645

Comment: it shows             E/Volley: [1581] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://54.193.70.29:8080/ghosanapatra/message/addMessageA?message=message&cId=1&heading=football&eId=1&wId=268&name=amir&memberFbId=12154465461321333&phone=9860324567  error

Comment: its internal server error. you has to check internally. but suggest you don't pass other language except English

Answer (score 0):

You need to put .trim() only not use replace.

```
          String   header=sirsak.getText().toString().trim();
```